# How to convert multipolygon to multilinestring

Tags: postgis

I try to convert my multipolygon layer to a multilinestring layer. In the [postgis codumentation](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_ExteriorRing.html)
I found this example:

> (...) -- If you have a table of MULTIPOLYGONs
>   -- and want to return a MULTILINESTRING composed of the exterior rings of 
>   each polygon
>   
>   `SELECT gid, ST_Collect(ST_ExteriorRing(the_geom)) AS erings
>       FROM (SELECT gid, (ST_Dump(the_geom)).geom As the_geom
>               FROM sometable) As foo
>   GROUP BY gid;`
>
> (...)

My postgresql connection is called `database`, schema `public`, default 
primary key field `gid`, default geometry field  `geom`, my 
multipolygon layer `poly_layer`.

How can I convert the layer `poly_layer` into a new multilinestring layer 
`line_layer`?

Answer (score 13):

You probably want to use ST_Boundary.  ST_ExteriorRing will just give your the outter ring of the polygon.  http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Boundary.html

```
SELECT gid, ST_Boundary(geom)::geometry(MULTILINESTRING,4326) As geom
    INTO line_layer
    FROM poly_layer;
```

Change the 4326 to whatever your srid is.

Comment: Thanks, I started to collect some sql commands because I use more and more postgis while editing in qgis. Sometimes qgis tools don't work and it's good to know more "powerful" tools.